# Развернуть свернутое окно

Tags: c++, windows

Как можно средствами C++ развернуть свернутую программу и сделать её окно активным?

Comment: `ShowWindow` с флагом `SW_RESTORE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>    
HWND hWnd = ::FindWindow(NULL, ("Name of the window")); // Ищем HWND окна по имени
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SW_RESTORE);
```